# Is there a verb that means continuously dropping or continuously oozing?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Non-stop dropping or dripping maybe.

Comment: Since you don't like 'oozing', how about 'seeping'? Or 'dribbling'?

Comment: -1 for demonstrating *no* research (for example, consulting a thesaurus) and using a sentence fragment in the body of your question.

Answer (score -1):

Try [trickle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trickle)

> to issue or fall in drops
>
> to flow in a thin gentle stream(stream is a continuous flow of things)